# Hi, I'm creating a music player I have this issue

Tags: memory-leaks, notifications, crash, updating, android-music-player

It says in logcat, NotificationService     system_server                        E  Package enqueue rate is 5.001587. Shedding 0|wills.music|1|null|10477. package=wills.music

could this also cause to crash when playing music or random, it crashes too, like restarts, when playing song, please help.

I'm not sure how to fix, am thinking the notification, is running constantly, like keeps updating state, otherwise not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i have found an answer to my question, the reason it said that is because I updated notification in a void that is duration and stuff means mediaplayer working calling to many updates past 10, so I ok now as android has a limit as to how much notification can be updated only 10 times in one go.